# How to swap only numeric values in each line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I need to swap only numeric values in each line after specific string "PIC" using sed. 
For example:

`hello PIC A(12), and this PIC B(11)`

The desired output is :

`hello PIC B(11), and this PIC A(12)`

The characters "B" and "A" might differ in other lines, but the string PIC is always there.

I am trying to use sed command :

`echo "hello PIC A(12), and this PIC B(11)" | sed '/PIC X(12)/s/PIC X(12)/PIC X(11)/g'`

but seems not working properly.

All responses are appreciated.

Comment: Is `12`  a fixed value? If not, try `sed -E 's/(PIC )([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))(.*PIC )([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))/\1\4\3\2/'`

Comment: great! It is working! So, in the file there are a lot of lines and with different length but there is always PIC A(<num>) values, so your code seems changing everything. ! Thank you @WiktorStribiżew !!!

Comment: Can I know where you learned using sed command ? I am facing a lot of situations where I need to use this tool . Kindly, thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I have been using Linux for almost two years now, and almost all my `sed` knowledge comes from SO and related sites. Follow the tag, try to answer the questions, even if you do not post them you will learn a lot.  Where `sed` is not enough or too cumbersome, I switch to Perl. `awk` has proven a nice alternative when the strings can be treated as some separator delimited strings.

Comment: @Sunny, fwiw, I just wrote a sed tutorial & reference [here](https://alexharv074.github.io/2019/04/16/a-sed-tutorial-and-reference.html). Your feedback welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `substitute` command directly since it will only change the lines where the match is found.

Use this POSIX ERE

```
sed -E 's/(PIC )([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))(.*PIC )([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))/\1\4\3\2/'
```

Or, POSIX BRE

```
sed 's/\(PIC \)\([A-Z]([0-9]*)\)\(.*PIC \)\([A-Z]([0-9]*)\)/\1\4\3\2/'
```

The two versions differ in the parentheses escaping: in POSIX BRE, `\(...\)` denote capturing groups and `(` and `)` are matching literal parentheses, while in POSIX ERE, it is vice versa.

POSIX ERE pattern details:

- `(PIC )` - Group 1: `PIC` and space
- `([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))` - Group 2: any uppercase ASCII letter, `(`, 1+ digits, `)`
- `(.*PIC )` - Group 3: any 0 or more chars, `PIC`, space
- `([A-Z]\([0-9]+\))` - Group 4: an uppercase letter, `(`, 1+ digits, `)`.

Answer (score 1):

if data in 'd' file, tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/(hello PIC )(\w+)(\S+, and this PIC )(\w+)/\1\4\3\2/' d
```

Comment: Never worked with .d files, but I am sure I will use that along in the future. Thank you for response!

Comment: `d` is just (admittedly cryptically!) the name of the input file, it's not an extension or anything interesting. It could have been named `file` or `foo` or anything else - it's just a plain old text file.

Comment: oh got it! Thank you @EdMorton!

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(PIC [[:upper:]]([0-9]*)\)\(.*\)\(PIC [[:upper:]]([0-9]*)\)/\3\2\1/' file
hello PIC B(11), and this PIC A(12)
```

If you don't have a POSIX sed (e.g. old sed on Solaris) then set `LC_ALL=C` and change `[:upper:]` to `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! :)

Comment: Hey Ed, I was trying to shift three words with the same command you posted, but it is not helping.. I was trying to shift :
If for example : OCCURS ## TIMES PIC ##(##) 
and need to make PIC ##(##) OCCURS ## TIMES .. numbers instead of hash.. I was trying to understand the sequence when you call the strings. 
I tried `` sed -E 's/(OCCURS\[0-9]+\)(TIMES+\)(PIC\[0-9]\([0-9]+\))/\3\1\2/' ``

Comment: @Sunny why aren't you using [the answer you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55802457/1745001)? In any case, post a new question with it's own [mcve] to get help.

Comment: @Sunny do ask a new question but first - what do you think `TIMES+` means in a regexp? Also, you seem to have blanks in your string (e.g. `OCCURS ## TIMES`) but no blanks nor metachars that would match them in your regexp (e.g. `(OCCURS[0-9]+)(TIMES+)`) so that's one reason it'll never match the string.

Comment: yeah, I am trying to find matching questions from website before asking, but didn't find it yet. And yeah, I got that after sending you the code , so I tried this `` sed -E 's/(OCCURS[0-9]\)(TIMES\)(PIC[0-9]([0-9])\)/\3\1\2/' ``, but didn't work as well

Comment: How **could** it work when your string contains spaces but your regexp doesn't? If you want to match a string like `xxx yyyy` which has spaces in the middle then you need to write a regexp that accounts for spaces in the middle, e.g. some variation of `x+ +y+`, not just `x+y+` with no spaces between.

Comment: I got this example from website, I am not sure how to really use regexp, so I thought that would work.. So, yeah